# Change a signed apk version code

Tags: android, version, keystore

I have this signed APK and I need to change the version-code in the manifest, because I lost the keystore ( #*!$@#&£!! ).
I've seen the question [How can I update the version of an APK which I did not create myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980791/how-can-i-update-the-version-of-an-apk-which-i-did-not-create-myself?rq=1) , but no success... please help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use apktool to decompile that apk then change the version in manifest. But the problem is you have to recompile it again then you need to sign the apk with jarsigner. There you need the keystore to sign the apk again. and to update the previous apk you need to use the same keystore.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create new sign apk without KeyStore file.
if Your app new on google play and not more download.
 then You want create new sign apk with different package name and new Keystore file. 
and upload it on GooglePlayStore.
other options are available but i think it is risky.

Comment: yes But if Your apk is not much download then You want to upload new apk.
other wise you face that problem every Time.
and if the small mistake in that than your app will be crashes. 
so i telling you